# How do I use Stylus style sheets with Angular 4 Ahead of Time compilation?

Tags: angular, stylus

I created an Angular 4 quick start project a few days back, and just for the hell of it I tried naming all my style sheets `.styl` and put [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) code in them. Against all my expectations, it actually worked! When using the development server all my stylus sheets have been transpiled down to css and works just as expected.

However, now I'm following the [guide for Ahead Of Time compilation (AOT)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) which went smoothly until I tried serving the final build. There are no styles whatsoever. The app appears to work, but it's all black text on a white background with no structure.

Converting my style sheets to CSS "fixes" the problem.

So my question is, how do I get transpiled style languages like Stylus, LESS and Sass to work with Angular 4 AOT compilation? I'm assuming there's just a setting or plugin I need to include somewhere.